# spring security facebook plugin (Grails) web service access

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am quite new to Grails and the plugin usage. right now I am trying to build restful services using grails. I need some kind of authentication for user so for that I am using spring-security-facebook plugin for grails. It works very well for all my web pages. but I need to perform
`<facebookAuth:connect />`
operation for an Android application. Is it possible to call spring security facebook plugin's user creation or authentication methods using some kind of restful web service? 
As right now I am using webview in android app to put the login page in it but it does not give native app feeling.

Any pointers will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are special type of authentication for this: [JSON Authentication](http://splix.github.com/grails-spring-security-facebook/guide/3%20Usage.html#3.5%20Json%20Authentication)

In short: you should post Facebook `access_token`, plugin will authentication FB user (create if nedeed) and respond with JSON containing user details.

Comment: thankyou for the hint. I had a doubt here. So for my android app I will perform the authentication using facebook SDK and pass the access token to GET www.myste.com/j_spring_security_facebook_json?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN> correct?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ServiceList2/j_spring_security_facebook_json?access_token=AAAFEWKgUG5kBAD8TAp9RHo5MQy8Qp5kXaN4HNWLaNSEp0shjKHZB3LE2KLnY2IKv4Nvb9bMM2mCT4yqaBmaPA......... when I am trying this I get http 404.. I am not sure whats that I am doing wrong

Comment: grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.filter.type='transparent,cookieDirect,json'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.filter.json.processUrl='/j_spring_security_facebook_json'  I have added these lines in config.groovy

Comment: Error 2013-02-03 15:38:24,612 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR facebook.FacebookAuthProvider  - Creating user w/o access_token
| Error 2013-02-03 15:38:24,615 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR [/ServiceList2].[grails-errorhandler]  - Servlet.service() for servlet grails-errorhandler threw exception
Message: Cannot get property 'accessToken' on null object

Comment: Looks like a bug. Could your create a new issue at https://github.com/splix/grails-spring-security-facebook/issues?state=open ? Don't forget to add log output

Comment: filed the issue https://github.com/splix/grails-spring-security-facebook/issues/31